Timer in not working as expected in LWC
Below is the code for timer which is not working as expected
HTML code:
<template>     
<lightning-card title="Styling using dynamic CSS">
        <div class="dynamicDiv sldx-box slds-box slds-box_small">
            <p class="dynamicP" style={getStyle}>
                {percentage}
            </p>
        </div>
        <lightning-button label="Start timer" onclick={handleStartTimer}></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button label="Reset timer" onclick={handleResetTimer}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

JS File:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class LwcStyling extends LightningElement {
    percentage = 0;

    handleStartTimer(event){
        setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
        function myTimer(){
            this.percentage += 1;
            console.log(`hi ${this.percentage}`);
        }
    }
    //this will reset the timer
    resetPercentageChange(event){
        this.percentage = 0;
    }
    get getStyle(){
        return `width: ${this.percentage}% ; background-color: green`;
    }
}

Here I was expecting as the timer increments it will increment the percentage value as well but when I tried to console the percentage in the same method NAN was printed in the console.

When you declare a function via function keyword it will have its own this. Docs:

Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the base object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.)

Therefore inside myTimer the value of this.percentage is undefined so adding 1 to it will result in NaN.
Just using an arrow function will fix it since they inherit this:
handleStartTimer(event){
    setInterval(() => {
        this.percentage += 1;
        console.log(`hi ${this.percentage}`);
    }, 1000);
}

Another way to fix this issue is binding the value of this via bind() method:
handleStartTimer(event){
    setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
    function myTimer(){
        this.percentage += 1;
        console.log(`hi ${this.percentage}`);
    }.bind(this);
}


Had a feeling that this was due to Javascript's odd handling of this, but wasn't quite sure.
